# Am I allowed to pass unequipped weapons (or items) to any survivor?

Tags: dead-of-winter

What is the rule regarding passing an **unequipped** weapon to a survivor that is not in your location?

For example, if I pickup a gun at the police station and want to pass it to another player that has a survivor at the grocery store.  Can I pass the player the card to equip to that survivor? Or would I have to move to that survivor's location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of moves that involve giving cards to other players.  They are **Hand Off** and **Request**.  The one you probably want is request.

> **Request**: During his turn a player may request 1 or more item cards from other players. Other players may give the requesting player an item card from their hand, if they do, that card must be revealed and immediately played. The requested card cannot be added to the crisis.

Request allows a player, on his turn, to get cards from other players as long as he plays it immediately.  I'm presuming that the card you want to give to someone is unequipped so in your hand.

> **Hand Off**: During his turn a player may have a survivor he controls that has an item equipped hand that item off to another survivor at the same location. When an item is handed off it is unequipped from the survivor that is handing it off and is immediately equipped to the survivor that it is being handed to.

Hand off is basically if a survivor already has an item equipped (i.e. it is "in play" and out of your godly control to move around to other survivors without restriction), then he or she can give the item to another survivor in the same location.

So, yes, you can pass that unequipped card but not on your turn.  You have to wait until that player's turn before they can request it from you to place on that survivor.

Comment: Great thanks, that last paragraph answers my question. I find it strange that I can't pass an item in my hand to another player unless they request it though.

Comment: I'm sure you can offer it.  I doubt it's a "no telling them what you have unless they guess" sort of thing.  It probably simply meant they can only receive it on their turn.

Comment: OK fair enough, I guess it doesn't really break the gameplay or anything like that. I would see the advantage of waiting for their turn in case a player before them needs that item in a desperate situation.  Thanks again. Look forward to my next play :)

Comment: I was thinking more it would suck if they had already gone before you and there was going to be a colony phase effect after your turn that would hurt that survivor because you weren't able to give that item to the survivor, but I guess that's the consequence of having used up their turn already and taken their actions. The survivors they control can no longer be changed in any way.  I haven't played the game more than once so don't remember if this is something that can actually happen though (greater chance of bad stuff happening during colony phase because of not having some item equipped).

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, items (equipped or unequipped) don't come into play during the colony phase.  My initial concern was if it make "logistical game sense" to be able to pass cards around to different survivors. Like if I picked up the gun at the police station how does it get to the grocery store. I guess it's more of an immersion issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you equip to your character and then do a hand off in the same turn if they are located at the same place?

Comment: I don't see any mention of a restriction on the order or these actions, so your suggestion seems reasonable.